# How to backup complete phone (8.1)

Tags: 8.1, lumia

I want to make a **complete** backup (system image) of my phone, and I remember reading somewhere that that's possible. However, now when searching for it, all I can find, both on the phone and on the web, are instructions on how to backup settings etc.

So how do I backup the whole phone?

Comment: Did you find anything? I'd like to do complete backup too, I don't want to loose installed applications which are not available in store anymore.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot simply backup the whole phone as a single system image. WP8.1 has a built-in backup feature that will store things like startscreen layout, installed apps (just the list, not necessarily the data), text messages etc. on OneDrive.

You can also [use this app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm) to export messages & contacts without storing them on OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`<padding for short comment>`